# how to create a CA Certificate in java

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, ca

I want to create a CA self signed certificate in java. 
I have already created a self signed certificate using bouncy castle but how to add basic constraints to this cert to be CA certificate .
Thanks

Comment: Please, add the code you are using now. Do you need help about coding with bouncycastle or about how to build a CA certificate in general?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code below to create a self-signed certificate with `basicConstraints` extension:

```
public static Certificate selfSign(KeyPair keyPair, String subjectDN) throws OperatorCreationException, CertificateException, IOException
{
    Provider bcProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(bcProvider);

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date startDate = new Date(now);

    X500Name dnName = new X500Name(subjectDN);
    BigInteger certSerialNumber = new BigInteger(Long.toString(now)); // <-- Using the current timestamp as the certificate serial number

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(startDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); // <-- 1 Yr validity

    Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

    String signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256WithRSA"; // <-- Use appropriate signature algorithm based on your keyPair algorithm.

    ContentSigner contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(signatureAlgorithm).build(keyPair.getPrivate());

    JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(dnName, certSerialNumber, startDate, endDate, dnName, keyPair.getPublic());

    // Extensions --------------------------

    // Basic Constraint
    BasicConstraints basicConstraints = new BasicConstraints(true); // <-- true for CA, false for EndEntity

    certBuilder.addExtension(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.19"), true, basicConstraints); // Basic Constraints is usually marked as critical.

    // -------------------------------------

    return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(bcProvider).getCertificate(certBuilder.build(contentSigner));
}
```